# Spring Data REST without Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have been looking at **Spring Data REST** to consider using it in our project and on the [Spring website](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) it mentions that it currently uses Spring MVC, but in the next version: *...will allow you to export your repositories in non-Servlet HTTP environments using high-throughput non-blocking IO, and will provide enhanced HTML5 capabilities.*

Does anyone recommend any approach for frontend integration for this *next version*?

Thanks.